# Шаблонный атрибут класса

Tags: c++

Условно зададим класс `cell`, описывающий треугольную ячейку.

```
class cell 
{
public:
    cell() = default;
    cell(size_t number, std::array<size_t, 3> faces, std::array<size_t, 3> neighbours);

private:
    size_t _number;
    std::array<size_t, 3> _faces;
    std::array<size_t, 3> _neighbours;
};
```

Как можно задать атрибут класса таким способом, чтобы класс подходил для ячеек любой формы?
По ощущениям это должно выглядеть так:

```
template<typename SIZE>
class cell 
{
public:
    cell() = default;
    cell(size_t number, std::array<size_t, SIZE> faces, std::array<size_t, SIZE> neighbours);

private:
    size_t _number;
    std::array<size_t, SIZE> _faces;
    std::array<size_t, SIZE> _neighbours;
};
```

Но как оно должно выглядеть на самом деле?

Comment: ¿Ну так а что не так с этим кодом по-вашему?

Comment: Редко пишу на C++. Выглядит топорно, превращать класс в шаблон только из-за числа граней, такое ощущение, что есть более удачный способ

Comment: Нет никакого другого способа. Если не хотите задавать размер во время компиляции и работать с массивами - используйте `std::vector`.

Comment: Интересно как   три целочисленных типа будут описывать треугольную ячейку....

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Тут конечно лучше иметь ссылки на ячейки, а не на их позицию в массиве ячеек, но ссылки это у меня пока что не первое, что приходит в голову.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почти так. Получается, вы хотите создать описание класса на базе которого должны формироваться уже конкретные классы, например: `cell<3>` или `cell<5>`. Т.е. раз весь ваш тип логически зависит от числа вершин, то шаблон класса тут идеально подходит.

Но! Параметром шаблона у вас должен быть не тип, а число (обратите внимание на первую строку):

```
    template<size_t SIZE>
        class cell 
        {
        public:
            cell() = default;
            cell(size_t number, std::array<size_t, SIZE> faces, std::array<size_t, SIZE> neighbours);
        private:
            size_t _number;
            std::array<size_t, SIZE> _faces;
            std::array<size_t, SIZE> _neighbours;
        };
```

Иначе ваш пример не скомпилируется, т.к. вы передаёте шаблонному классу `cell` какой-то тип как параметр и на базе этого типа конструируете `std::array`. Например, при `SIZE = float` тип вашего массива будет `array<size_t, float>` — что не имеет смысла.

Comment: За что дан минус? Вполне нормально же